# RegEX match only first value

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello in regex how can i find ONLY first two number that start with "39"?

I tried with

```
^(.*?)39
```

but it deletes the second match also. Example:

```
393905598787
393400048083
```

I want:

```
3905598755
3400048099
```

With my code, the result is this:

```
05598755
3400048099
```

The `05598755` is wrong because I have two `39`s at the beginning, but I want to discard only the first `39`.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the rest of the line after you match `39` at the start of the line and use

*Find What*: `^39(.*)`
*Replace With*: `$1`

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `39` - a fixed value
- `(.*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): matches the rest of the line.

See the demo settings:

[image]

If the `39` is not at the start of the line, use `^(.*?)39(.*)`  and replace with `$1$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

Find:`^\d{2}(.*)` or `^\d\d(.*)`
Replace with:`$1`

Was working for me ...